# How turn off the beep sound in guard rb-notifu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, notify

When i use

> bundle exec guard

it notify me about test result with 'Beep' 3 times sound. I can't find where it turned off?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Notifu notifier docs, which describes the options take by the notifier: http://rubydoc.info/github/guard/guard/master/Guard/Notifier/Notifu

So you can disable sound by adding:

```
notification :notifu, :nosound => true
```

to your Guardfile.